# What is regularity of solutions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I have been reading a publication involving numerical methods for PDEs and stumbled upon the term "regularity of solutions". My internet search hasn't given much useful information on this. Does someone have a precise definition of what regularity of solutions [of PDE] means?

Comment: It's not a precise definition but more a hint to the theory of regularity of solutions (the basics of which you will find in any text book about PDE). These theorems tells you under which condition on a differential operator ( (strongly) elliptic, parabolic, hyperbolic, it's order, smoothness of its coefficients, lower order terms and so on), the boundary conditions (if any), the geometry of the domain, etc) regularity conditions on the right hand side of the solution allow you to make conclusions on the smoothness of a solution.

Comment: To see some typical examples you may have a look at Gilbarg and Trudingers monograph on second order elliptic partial differential equations.